# release:perform creating wrong folder on server

Tags: linux, maven, scp, maven-release-plugin

I use `maven release:perform` to deploy the releases. In the distributionManagement is set this url:

```
<url>scpexe://user@myserver/</url>
```

Unfortunately all the `.xml`,`.sha1`,`.md5`, and last but not least all the `.jar`-Files are placed into a new directory in the filesystem's root!

Can i **specify on server-side** a concrete folder where to place theese files?

Comment: How about just `scpexe://user@myserver/my/sub/folder`?

Comment: And tell the world details about my server? Is there a better way?

Comment: Why are you concerned about this? URL already contains the server name, or IP. This is a lot more than just path on the FS.

Comment: And if i change the os and indirectly the path too? I can not go to everyone who has downloaded old releases and ask them to let me rewrite the url on their old downloads.

Comment: But that's always the problem when you change repository, for whatever repository. Let's say you deploy to an Artifactory. If you change to Nexus in the future, you'll have to update the projects.

Comment: You tell me all who switch to artifactory visit physically the downloaders, ring their bell on the door?

Comment: I'll put it differently. Let's say tomorrow you don't want to deploy to `scpexe://user@myserver` but to `ssh:git:...`. The same problem appears. Or I'm completely way off base and should get a coffee.

Comment: To switch the directory and to switch the protocol are differnt things.

Comment: Agree but isn't the issue the same?

Comment: No. The question is about directory, not about protocol.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104525/discussion-between-tunaki-and-peter-rader).